# Excel function to search for a string of letters in a column

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet

I've a column with cells containing the word "Google" and "Google.com" as well. 
If I search for the keyword "Google" using the formula =COUNTIF(B1:B940,"Google") it doesn't count the "Google.com" ones. Which formula can I use which gives me the count for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for your *specific* case, it might be preferable to just do:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B940,"Google")+COUNTIF(B1:B940,"Google.com")
```

For something more complex, `countif` allows wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B940,"Google*")
```

but that may pick up stuff you're not interested in, such as `Google ate my homework`.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Can you also please tell me the difference between the above two functions mentioned in your answer because both give different results.

Comment: @Peaceful, they should only give a different result if you have cells starting with `Google` but that are neither `Google` nor `Google.com`. This includes, for example, those that may _look_ like `Google` but have spaces at the end - they won't be included in the first but will be picked up by the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wildcard `*` in your search term, like `"Google*"`:

[image]

Other wildcards like `?` can also be used if you know the length of the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks @Werner Instead of applying it for a specific range can I apply this function to the whole sheet?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior: You'd have to place the formula on a different sheet, otherwise you'll receive circular reference warnings. For the reference, [click in the top-left of the sheet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ALJFG.png) which should select the range `1:1048576`, implying row 1 through 1048576 (the last row).